# Android: Don't understand strict error message

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I need help in understanding the following strict error message on my emulator which causes my app to stall (I am calling an activity) and the emulator to restart:

```
05-31 13:37:59.080    1298-1804/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
05-31 13:38:00.170    1824-1824/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-31 13:38:00.170    1824-1824/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-31 13:38:00.520    1855-1855/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-31 13:38:00.570    1514-1514/com.android.phone E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
05-31 13:38:00.690    1868-1875/com.android.providers.calendar E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
05-31 13:38:02.840    1514-1514/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager﹕ [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: ICC ID is null or empty.
05-31 13:38:03.060      943-943/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 943: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-31 13:38:03.160    1419-1908/android.process.media E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 67 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/internal.db-wal
05-31 13:38:03.730    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-31 13:38:03.730    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-31 13:38:03.860    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-31 13:38:03.860    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-31 13:38:03.860    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
05-31 13:38:03.860    1298-1315/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
05-31 13:38:03.880    1298-1344/system_process E/ConnectivityService﹕ Exception in setupDataActivityTracking java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '14 idletimer add eth0 5 0' failed with '400 14 Failed to add interface'
05-31 13:38:04.300    1987-1994/com.android.email E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
05-31 13:38:05.080    1987-1987/com.android.email E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1c016d19 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1c016d19 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1072)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:966)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1768)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
            at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
            at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
            at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
            at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
            at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
            at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-31 13:38:06.280    2057-2057/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-31 13:38:06.280    2057-2057/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-31 13:38:07.750    1868-2093/com.android.providers.calendar E/SQLiteLog﹕ (284) automatic index on view_events(_id)
05-31 13:38:08.070    1909-1918/com.android.mms E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
            at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.<init>(PduPersister.java:288)
            at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.getPduPersister(PduPersister.java:299)
            at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:224)
            at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:626)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-31 13:38:09.050    1941-1950/com.android.calendar E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.<init>(ContentResolver.java:2447)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-31 13:38:09.090    2067-2067/com.anton.book E/SQLiteLog﹕ (284) automatic index on program(_id)
05-31 13:38:14.290     954-1294/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
05-31 13:38:16.310      943-943/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 943: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-31 13:38:16.330    1298-1586/system_process E/﹕ QemuPipeStream::readFully failed (buf 0x7f1b915b0000): Bad address
```

Any help how these error messages can generally be understood/analysed is highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It's saying that it couldn't create the SharedPreferences file.

Comment: There is only one line out of all of that LogCat dump that pertains to you:
`05-31 13:38:09.090    2067-2067/com.anton.book E/SQLiteLog﹕ (284) automatic index on program(_id)`. Note that I am even guessing that this error pertains to you, given your Stack Overflow name and the application ID recorded in LogCat both referring to "anton". Off the cuff, I am not sure what that is or why it is being logged with error severity. The rest is coming from other apps on your device, written by other developers.